# How can I get user input from an entry? GTK 4 C

Tags: c, gtk4

I'm trying to get what it's been typed in an entry and store it to afterwards use it elsewhere in my app, but I'm having a hard time trying to figure it out because functions like gtk_entry_get_text() aren't in gtk4 so I'm using an entry buffer to get content from entries.

Additionally, can somebody explain to me why there's no examples on gtk4? or why is everyone still providing examples with gkt3? Considering some functions in gkt3 are deprecated.

Here's what I'm doing:

```c
static void on_show_text_from_buffer(GtkWidget *p_button, gpointer user_data) {
   gtk_button_set_label(GTK_BUTTON(p_button), "Clicked!");
   g_print("%s\n", (char *)user_data); // I wanna print out what it's been typed in here
}

static void on_activate(GtkApplication *app) {
   // Create a new window
   GtkWidget *window = gtk_application_window_new(app);
   GtkWidget *p_grid = gtk_grid_new();
   GtkWidget *p_button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Click me");

   gtk_grid_set_column_spacing(GTK_GRID(p_grid), 16);
   gtk_grid_set_row_spacing(GTK_GRID(p_grid), 16);

   gtk_grid_set_row_homogeneous(GTK_GRID(p_grid), TRUE);
   gtk_grid_set_column_homogeneous(GTK_GRID(p_grid), TRUE);

   GtkEntryBuffer *p_buffer_1 = gtk_entry_buffer_new(NULL, -1);

   GtkWidget *p_entry_1 = gtk_entry_new_with_buffer(p_buffer_1);
   GtkWidget *p_entry_2 = gtk_entry_new_with_buffer(p_buffer_1);

   gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(p_grid), GTK_WIDGET(p_entry_1), 0, 0, 3, 1);
   gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(p_grid), GTK_WIDGET(p_entry_2), 0, 1, 3, 1);
   gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(p_grid), GTK_WIDGET(p_button), 0, 2, 3, 1);

   char *p_text_in_entry = g_strdup(gtk_entry_buffer_get_text(p_buffer_1));

   g_signal_connect(p_button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(on_show_text_from_buffer),
                    p_text_in_entry);

   gtk_window_set_child(GTK_WINDOW(window), p_grid);
   gtk_window_present(gtk_window(window));
}
```

Comment: @xing sudo pacman -S gtk4

Answer (score 1):

[`GtkEntry`](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/class.Entry.html) implements [`GtkEditable`](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/iface.Editable.html) interface. So you can do `gtk_editable_get_text (GTK_EDITABLE (entry))` to get the text in a `GtkEntry`. Thus you don't need to set custom buffer to get the text in a `GtkEntry`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the variable char* declared in "on_activate" loses its value when this function is finished, whereas the buffer is retained as a widget.
Accordingly, the buffer must be passed and then passed to a local variable in the "on_show_text_from_buffer" function.
Here's how it works:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void on_show_text_from_buffer(GtkWidget *p_button, gpointer user_data) {
   gtk_button_set_label(GTK_BUTTON(p_button), "Clicked!");
   char *p_text_in_entry = g_strdup(gtk_entry_buffer_get_text(user_data));
   g_print("%s\n", p_text_in_entry); // I wanna print out what it's been typed in here
}

static void on_activate(GtkApplication *app) {
 // Create a new window
 GtkWidget *window = gtk_application_window_new(app);
 GtkWidget *p_grid = gtk_grid_new();
 GtkWidget *p_button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Click me");

 gtk_grid_set_column_spacing(GTK_GRID(p_grid), 16);
 gtk_grid_set_row_spacing(GTK_GRID(p_grid), 16);

 gtk_grid_set_row_homogeneous(GTK_GRID(p_grid), TRUE);
 gtk_grid_set_column_homogeneous(GTK_GRID(p_grid), TRUE);

 GtkEntryBuffer *p_buffer_1 = gtk_entry_buffer_new(NULL, -1);

 GtkWidget *p_entry_1 = gtk_entry_new_with_buffer(p_buffer_1);
 GtkWidget *p_entry_2 = gtk_entry_new_with_buffer(p_buffer_1);

 gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(p_grid), GTK_WIDGET(p_entry_1), 0, 0, 3, 1);
 gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(p_grid), GTK_WIDGET(p_entry_2), 0, 1, 3, 1);
 gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(p_grid), GTK_WIDGET(p_button), 0, 2, 3, 1);

 g_signal_connect(p_button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(on_show_text_from_buffer),
               p_buffer_1);

 gtk_window_set_child(GTK_WINDOW(window), p_grid);
 gtk_window_present(GTK_WINDOW(window));
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    GtkApplication *app;
    int status;

    app = gtk_application_new ("stackof.holger.entry", G_APPLICATION_DEFAULT_FLAGS);

    g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (on_activate), NULL);
    status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
    g_object_unref (app);

    return status;
 }
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

simply

g_signal_connect(e, "changed",
G_CALLBACK(on_key_press), this);

where e is the GtkEntry